# difference between popen and exec python

Tags: python

Can anyone explain what is the difference between Popen and exec in Python

Im able to accomplish the same task to execute a program dynamically using exec and Popen.

The code here uses the EXEC approach but what will happen if I use the Popen approach.

code1.py

```
def runjob(src, job):
    x = "from {src} import *" +  '\n' + "{job}(parm1=)"
    y = x.format(src=src, job=job)
    exec ( 'from ' + src + ' import *' + '\n' + job  + '(10)' )


def main():
    runjob(c:/python27/test_job', 'il')
```

code2.py

```
def fl(parm=None):
    print 'function1'
    print parm

def f2(parm=None):
    print 'function 2'
    print parm

def f3(parm=None):
    print 'function 3'
    print parm
```

Comment: x, y, fl, f2, f3.. what's all that noise??

Answer (score 4):

`exec` and `Popen` are more or less unrelated.

---

[`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) is used to run a piece of python code.

> This statement supports dynamic execution of Python code. The first expression should evaluate to either a string, an open file object, or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless a syntax error occurs). If it is an open file, the file is parsed until EOF and executed.

---

[`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) is a class that allows to you to run any programm.

> Execute a child program in a new process. It offers a lot of flexibility so that developers are able to handle the less common cases not covered by the convenience functions.

Not only can you run other programms, you can also read their output and set a number of usefull options, like the working directory or if a new terminal should be opened etc.